# Force variables with the same name to overwrite from y dataset

Tags: r

I want to merge variables with the same name so values from the y dataset overwrite those in the x datatset.

This code should produce a replica of b because a$V2 should be overwritten by b$V2.

Instead I get V2.x and V2.y

```
a = data.frame(c("A","B","C","D"), c("1","2"))
names (a) = c("V1","V2")
b = data.frame(c("A","B","C","D"), c("3","4"))
names (b) = c("V1","V2")
merge.data.frame(a,b, by.x = "V1", by.y = "V1", all.y = T,)
```

Comment: Can I move this to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72764162/merge-variables-with-different-rows-in-r

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier with `rows_update`

```
library(dplyr)
rows_update(a, b, by = 'V1')
```

---

Or do an assign (`:=`) by joining with `data.table`, which updates the column 'V2' in 'a' by the column ('V2') from 'b' data

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[b, V2 := i.V2, on = .(V1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this one:

```
a$V2 <- b$V2
```

```
  V1 V2
1  A  3
2  B  4
3  C  3
4  D  4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse` to override the values you want after `merge`

```
df <- merge.data.frame(a,b, by = "V1")

df$V2 <- ifelse(df$V2.x == df$V2.y , df$V2.x , df$V2.y)

df |> subset(select = c(V1 , V2))
```

**Output**

```
  V1 V2
1  A  3
2  B  4
3  C  3
4  D  4
```