# Merge variables with different rows in R

Tags: r

```
a = data.frame(c("Joe","Bill","Frank"), c("30","31",""))
b = data.frame(c("Frank","Chuck"), c("32","40"))
names (a) = c("name","age")
names (b) = c("name","age")
```

How can I merge a, b to get:

Joe 30
Bill 31
Frank 32
Chuck 40

Answer (score 0):

Option using `full_join` and remove row with blank cell:

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%
  full_join(., b) %>%
  na_if("") %>%
  na.omit()
```

Output:

```
Joining, by = c("name", "age")
   name age
1   Joe  30
2  Bill  31
4 Frank  32
5 Chuck  40
```

Comment: But we don't want to delete people without an age:  a = data.frame(c("Joe","Bill","Frank"), c("","31",""))

Comment: @CharlesStangor, you can skip last two lines of code in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(a, b) %>% filter(age != "")

#>    name age
#> 1   Joe  30
#> 2  Bill  31
#> 3 Frank  32
#> 4 Chuck  40
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
subset(rbind(a,b) , age != "")
```

**output**

```
   name age
1   Joe  30
2  Bill  31
4 Frank  32
5 Chuck  40
```